# UserControl Property Changing

Tags: asp.net

I have created a User Control(Popupcontrol) and in that control i have created a property(PageType) and when i am using the Popupcontrol on the page then i set the property(pagetype) according to the page.
but now there is some problem i have to two button on the page and on the second button click i want to change the pagetype property .So is there any solution for the same.

Comment: please rewrite your question with punctuation. The question is hard to understand

Comment: so why don't you just set that property to the necessary value in the "second" button click handler?

Comment: if i am setting the property on the button click then it's not getting change bcause on the page load it set to previous defined property.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, it seems you bind the data (`PageType` property in your question) in the `Page_Load` event, instead of this it should be done in overrided `DataBind` method which should be called if the page is not in [post back](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) request (otherwise your data will be overwritting in the next `Page_Load` event as you mentioned in your comments):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBind();
    }
}

public override void DataBind()
{
    PageType = someValue;
}
```

after this your click handler may looks like:

```
protected void button2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PageType = someOtherValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the variable in a page load event? You may need to add:

```
if (!Page.IsPostback) {
    // Code here.
}
```